# The compiler dart2js crashed: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart2js

Hello I faced some issue when I built my Flutter app for web

**NOTE THAT MY APP RUNS WELL IN DEBUG MODE**

Module dart2js

My OS: **macOS Monterey - 12.3.1 (21E258)**

Dart Sdk build number **2.15.1**

### The full stack trace

```
The compiler crashed: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      BinaryPrinter.visitExtension (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:2501:73)
#1      Extension.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:1601:38)
#2      BinaryPrinter.writeExtensionNode (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:479:10)
#3      BinaryPrinter.writeExtensionNodeList (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:376:7)
#4      BinaryPrinter.visitLibrary (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:1060:5)
#5      Library.accept (package:kernel/ast.dart:557:38)
#6      BinaryPrinter.writeLibraryNode (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:451:10)
#7      BinaryPrinter.writeLibraries (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:756:9)
#8      BinaryPrinter.writeComponentFile.<anonymous closure> (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:595:7)
#9      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:163:22)
#10     BinaryPrinter.writeComponentFile (package:kernel/binary/ast_to_binary.dart:577:14)
#11     KernelLoaderTask.load.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/kernel/loader.dart:242:19)
#12     CompilerTask.measureSubtask (package:compiler/src/common/tasks.dart:181:35)
#13     KernelLoaderTask.load.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/kernel/loader.dart:236:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     Compiler.runInternal (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:311:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
```